# Запятая перед как

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

"Ополчились на него(?) как на врага." 
Нужна запятая?

Comment: Указанная запятая нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна.

Розенталь: Приложение, присоединяемое союзом как со значением **«в качестве»**, не обособляется, если стоит **в конце предложения**, характеризует предмет с какой-либо одной стороны: *Я сохраню это письмо как память*. *Петр I не считал для себя зазорным работать как простой плотник.*

В данном случае субъекта посчитали врагом и в качестве врага на него ополчились.

Сравнительное значение (ополчились так, как ополчаются на врага) маловероятно - очень уж странный смысл получается: ополчились определенным образом, который похож на другой образ действия. Скорее ополчились, видя в нем врага, отождествляя с врагом, чем ополчились похожим образом.

Причинное значение (ополчились, потому что он враг) в конце предложения обычно не употребляется.

Так что остается значение "в качестве".

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь пишет, что оборот с "как" не обособляется, когда имеет значение приравнивания, отождествления с чем-то. Приводится похожий на Ваше предложение пример: Старайтесь смотреть на меня как на пациента, одержимого болезнью...